# Find all entire functions satisfying a condition

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

The question is to find all entire functions that satisfy the following condition: $|f(z)| \geq |z| + 1$

My attempt:

$|f(z)| \geq |z| + 1 \geq |z + 1|$

Letting $h(z) = \frac{z+1}{ f(z)}$, $h(z)$ is bounded and entire and therefore constant by Liouville's theorem.

Then $h(z) = \frac{z+1}{ f(z)} = C$, so $f(z) = (1/C)(z+1)$, where $C$ is a constant with $|C| >1$

is this work okay?

Comment: So far, it's almost okay. You have identified the candidates, except you have the wrong condition on the constant $C$. But the next question is whether those candidates do in fact satisfy the required inequality.

Comment: thanks for the response. How can I fix it?

Comment: Fix what? The inequality gives $\lvert h(z)\rvert \leqslant 1$, so the correct constraint is $\lvert C\rvert \leqslant 1$. Now consider a function $g(z) = K\cdot(z+1)$. Under which conditions do you have $\lvert g(z)\rvert \geqslant \lvert z\rvert + 1$ for all $z$?

Comment: if $|K| \geq \frac{|z| + 1}{|z+1|}$ for all z

Comment: And can that happen?

Comment: no since it should be less than 1? but that means that no functions can satisfy the inequality

Comment: That isn't the problem. $K$ would be $1/C$, so your argument already yields $\lvert K\rvert \geqslant 1$.

Comment: I see..because it wouldn't be holomorphic at z = -1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have correctly found that **if** $f$ is an entire function satisfying $\lvert f(z)\rvert \geqslant \lvert z\rvert +1$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$, then $f(z) = K\cdot (z+1)$ for some $K\in \mathbb{C}$. But then we have

$$\lvert f(-1)\rvert = 0 < \lvert -1\rvert + 1,$$

so such a function does not exist.

Another argument is to note that $\lvert f(z)\rvert \geqslant \lvert z\rvert + 1$ implies that $f$ has no zeros, hence $1/f$ is also an entire function, and that satisfies

$$\frac{1}{\lvert f(z)\rvert} \leqslant \frac{1}{\lvert z\rvert + 1}.$$

By Liouville's theorem, $1/f$ is constant, and since

$$\lim_{z\to \infty} \frac{1}{\lvert z\rvert + 1} = 0$$

we must have $1/f \equiv 0$. But then $f \equiv \infty$ is not an entire function.

Comment: got it, thank you so much